# DNN and Claims-Based Identity Using WIF

Tags: dotnetnuke, wif, claims-based-identity, adfs2.0

I'm quite surprised, but after a day of searching, I don't see any DNN authentication providers for WIF. I found a set of 3 articles, paraphrased as: "1) Hey, I found a solution that doesn't require a new provider, 2) woops, forgot something, 3) oh, and I forgot this other thing."

Has anyone heard of or implemented such a thing? I have a DNN web site for which I would like to implement a WIF provider to connect to ADFS 2.0. Both have been around for quite a while. Where is a good place to look?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Isn't DNN just ASP.NET? Why wouldn't you use the SAM/FAM from WIF then?

Comment: It is, but can you comment on DNN hosting solutions that don't give direct access to DNN's installation? I am not a DNN guru, but am under the impression if there's a authentication provider available, it's straightforward to implement in nearly every hosting situation, whereas the straight-ASP.Net approach may not work.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any existing solution, however, after integrating DNN with at least 60+ different authentication stores/systems I can say that it should be pretty easy to integrate.

As Brock mentioned, if you find an ASP.NET solution it is just a little bit of tweaking to get it to work for DNN.

Comment: Funny story... talking with Mark L and Aaron H from my company (Skyline), they suggested contacting you about this. Mark looked online for a quick solution to my problem and found a) this article, b) your response, and c) it was my question.

Comment: Is there any guidance written to make the tweaks to DNN required to hook up to ADFS?

Comment: Mark sorry for the delay, I don't check for replies here all that often.  Right now there isn't much documentation on Auth Providers, it is on my to-blog list....but has been there since 2009.....if I only had a clone!